# ReactJS - call function from broswer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, button, onclick

I started working with React and just converting an older web application into ReactJS.

My problem is that I load some content which later is added into a modal (dangerouslySetInnerHTML). The content includes `<input type="button" onclick="myFunc()">`

Previously I can just write a global function myFunc() and this was executed. But with ReactJS, I don't know how to do this. If I just write this function into the component I get `myFunc is not defined`.

Does someone have an idea of how to solve it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: For sure that's not the best way to use react, but if you absolutely need it you should call `window.myFunc()`

Comment: I would say the best way to solve it, is don't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and render this part in React too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write global functions in react. Somewhere inside the class, maybe in the constructor or in `componentDidMount` or something, just write `window.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using some kind of state management tool like Context or Redux. That way you can set a global function witch can be executed from anywhere in the app.